# sql.execute is not a function in node js and sql server?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to call a sql server stored procedure using node js. But then when I test the procedure, I get this error which says "SQL.EXECUTE" is not a function.
What exactly does that mean? I have tested the stored procedure with the following data from my c# code and it worked fine but it shows error when I try to call it in Node js

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'realm',
    password: 'friend',
    server: '172.10.3.22\\SQL2014',
    database: 'ElmaTest'
};

var updateMember = function( Country, Distributor,OilMerchant,FileName,CargoType,OperatorID) {
    return sql.execute( { //I get error pointing at this particular line
        procedure: "p_GetAllocationDetail",
        params: {
            Country: {
                type: sql.VARCHAR,
                val: Country
            },
            Distributor: {
                type: sql.VARCHAR,
                val: Distributor
            },
            OilMerchant: {
                type: sql.NVARCHAR,
                val: OilMerchant
            },
            FileName: {
                type: sql.VARCHAR,
                val: FileName
            },
            CargoType: {
                type: sql.VARCHAR,
                val: CargoType
            },
            OperatorID: {
                type: sql.VARCHAR,
                val: OperatorID
            }
        }
    } );
};

function  connecttoDb() {
  //  updateMember("elma","pass1234");
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log("message is for" + err);
        updateMember("Kenya","Total","Oilibya","","","Jessica");
    });
}

module.exports.datavalue = connecttoDb();
```

Comment: which version of mssql are you using? 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong according to the [documentation](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#quick-example).

It should be

```
var sql = require('mssql');
/*...*/

new sql.Request()
       .input('Country', sql.VarChar(50), Country)
       .input('Distributor', sql.VarChar(50), Distributor)
       .input( /* .... */)
       .execute('p_GetAllocationDetail').then(function(result) {
           console.dir(result);
       }).catch(function(err) {
           console.dir(err);
       });
```

In short: the `sql` object does not have an `execute` function. An instance of the `sql.Request()` object has an `execute()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this issue very well and discovered the following:

1. That this error occurred because the connection defined is not seen by the app.js project file.
2. That if the connection to database is written in another page, the Exports are not done properly.

An example of this is seen below:

*File: database.js*

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      database: 'Tiv',
      password: 'yesu'
      });
module.export =pool.promise();
```

This will give the error **db.execute is not a function**.
Because the line
module.export is wrong. it should have been
**module.exports =pool.promise();**

This is an omission of s in exports. So in the app.js file this database would be required and everything will work but when the view for this database is rendered the error will be thrown.
The file making this call might be like below:

*File: User.js*

```
const db = require('../utils/database');
module.exports = class memberInfo{
constructor(id,name,address,position){
      this.id =id;
      this.name = name;
      this.address =address;
      this.position =position;
    }
    static findAllUsers(){
         return db.execute('SELECT * FROM memberInfo');
    }
}
```

So in your case make sure your exports are really what you typed.
**module.exports.datavalue = connecttoDb();**

because it could have been

```
module.exports = connecttoDb();
```

That is all you need change.